# How to create database from schema.rb without initializing Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create all my tables from schema.rb

I used the command: "rake db:schema:load"

However, this fails because in one of my initializers, it is referencing a model/table that obviously doesn't exist (since the database is empty)

I could comment out these lines, and then run schema:load again, but is there an alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a check for the table existance in your initializer.

```
if TheModel.table_exists?
  // do something with the model
end
```

Comment: I ended up using this approach in the ActiveAdmin gem's initializer, since that gem loads completely improperly. Anyhow, +1.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer has less votes than other one. It's simplest and fully working. +1 from me :)

Answer (score 45):

Probably the fastest way is to just move the offending initializer to a temporary directory that is outside of the app, and then run your schema load. But if that doesn't work, or isn't an option for some reason, you could always work around that by creating a bare bones rails app to do the schema load:

1. Create a new rails app: `rails new (app)-fixer`
2. Copy your `gemfile` (unless there are specific exceptions) to the fixer app.
3. Copy your `database.yml` config to the fixer app.
4. Copy your `schema.rb` file to the fixer app.
5. Do all appropriate "bundle install" commands as needed for your app.
6. Then run `"rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load"`

That will build up a new database from scratch, based on your current schema.