# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord::Migration to change whole schema structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, database-migration

Is there a way generate a `ActiveRecord::Migration` to update all database structure?

Just like `rails generate migration ChangeWholeSchemaTables`

Comment: You could as well archive the current migration sequence, drop the database and fill in the schema from scratch with a new sequence of migrations.

Comment: Yes, you can have any number of changes in a single migration that you want.

Comment: When I am generating a new model, rails generates a migration automatically. I have added all my database modifications inside that file. At the result, tables weren't updated as I expected...

Answer (score 1):

To update all database structure you should use /db/schema.rb file.
I recommend that you check Chris Rueber answer for similar issue:
[How to create database from schema.rb without initializing Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035442/how-to-create-database-from-schema-rb-without-initializing-rails)

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it is a good way to do this. By doing this, there might be a mess in the following migrations...